# Replace HTML tags using Pandoc Lua filter when converting from markdown to HTML

Tags: html, lua, markdown, pandoc, xhtml-transitional

I have a markdown file that contains some HTML tags in it and one in particular, the `<br>` tag I would like to replace when converting to HTML using pandoc.  The issue is I would like to replace it with `<br />` due to some compatibility issues with some older renderers that complain about `<br>`.  I did try the following Lua filter when running the conversion but it did not do anything:

`filter.lua`:

```
function LineBreak (elem)
    return {
        pandoc.RawInline('html', '<br />')
    }
end
```

I'm using Pandoc version `2.13` running the following command with the following test file:

`Test.md`:

```
## Testing

Hello <br> World!
```

`pandoc --lua-filter filter.lua --to html5 Test.md`

I have also tried specifying `--to html4` but the output is still the same.  Is there a way to do this with Lua filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug this, we can first run `pandoc --to=native Test.md` to see how the input is parsed into pandoc's internal document representation. This yields

```hs
[Header 2 ("testing",[],[]) [Str "Testing"]
,Para [Str "Hello",Space,RawInline (Format "html") "<br>",Space,Str "World!"]]
```

The interesting part is that `<br>` is parsed as `RawInline (Format "html") "<br>"`, not as a linebreak. So we can modify the filter to match on that:

```lua
function RawInline (raw)
  if raw.format == 'html' and raw.text == '<br>' then
    return pandoc.RawInline('html', '<br />')
  end
end
```

This gives the desired result:

```
$ pandoc --lua-filter filter.lua --to html5 Test.md
<h2 id="testing">Testing</h2>
<p>Hello <br /> World!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I did not know about the --to=native which is amazing to help me understand how things are interpreted under the hood.  And of course the filter works beautifully!